# Python error syntax in the "tweepy" library

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, tweepy

I've got an issue with the tweepy library in Python. I had no problem during the installation of *brew, pip* and *tweepy*.

- Python version is **Python 2.7.18**.
- Pip version is **pip 21.3.1**
- Tweepy version is **4.3.0**

My code is the following:

```
import tweepy

consumer_key="XXX"
consumer_secret_key="XXX"
access_token="XXX-XXX"
access_token_secret="XXX"


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

print ("User Name:", api.me().name)
print ("Account (@):", api.me().screen_name)
```

My problem is this piece of code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy-4.3.0-py2.7.egg/tweepy/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tweepy.api import API
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy-4.3.0-py2.7.egg/tweepy/api.py", line 93
    self, auth=None, *, cache=None, host='api.twitter.com', parser=None,
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can't use that syntax with Python 2.7. You should be using Python 3 by now anyway.

Comment: Is there any reason to use a version of Python that's dead for nearly 2 years now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to using Python 2.7.

If you are using a library you need to use a version of Python that it supports. According to [Tweepy's documentation](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy), "Python 3.6 - 3.10 are supported."

If you persist with using Python 2.7 you could face issues with other libraries as well.